# Get Like/Comment counts of post with Facebook Graph API v2.9

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an application which allows customers to share a link to their Facebook using FB.ui, it's something like this

```
FB.ui(
{
    method: 'feed',
},
function (response) {
    // the response contains only post_id
    if (response && response.post_id) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

An example for post_id I got: 1329761410442716_1330464870372370

I'm trying to get like counts of this post using

https://graph.facebook.com/1329761410442716_1330464870372370/likes?summary=true&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN

Facebook returns message: **singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher**

I can get the like count with API v2.3 with that post_id, however my app is using API **v2.9**

Please show me the way, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the `/reactions` [edge](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/post/) for `/post`s. Have a look into the [Graph API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/reactions), there's also a field for `summary`.

So that's basically the way to go (did not test this one yet, cause the Graph API Explorer is not working at the moment):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{post-id}/reactions?summary=total_count&access_token={access-token}
```